# what is better...list of objects or map?

Tags: java, object, dictionary

I have pairs of two values - they could be translated to a map where you put key, value or to a list where you put objects that have the fields that in 'map' world are key and value.

Which is better from the design perspective?

Thank you,
Roxnaa

Comment: Everything depends on the context... What are you going to do with those structures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best bet here is **Map**.Cause List doesn't carry the key value pairs.

Using [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) only you can  get the value by key when ever you need..other wise(list) you need to bare more lines of code.

And finally It depends on you context.

Comment: Why exactly? For example, what if the pairs represent 2D points? You wouldn't be able to store both `(1,2)` and `(1,3)` in a `Map` since both use `1` as key. In such case, a `List` or `Set` is more appropriate. Again, everything depends on the context: what do the pairs represent and what is their purpose.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Then inOrder to recognize the 2D array OP should maintain a kwy right ??

Comment: We don't know if there exists a *unique key* which can be associated with each pair. We don't know if the OP *needs* to access pairs using a key. It might just be that he only needs to be able to store and iterate over the whole collection, or that he only needs access *by index*. In fact, we don't know *anything* about what the pairs represent, thus we cannot conclude *anything* about which is the better choice. There's no "best bet" here.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Agreed.Added *And finally It depends on you context.* :)

Comment: That's the *only* valid response, really. "Betting" on a `Map` being a better choice is not even relevant, there are just as many good reasons to prefer a `List`, a `Set` or even a plain array. This question simply cannot be answered without any information about the data, there simply is no answer to it in its current form.